# What kind of exception is 'Connection Timed Out' - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, exception

I'm working on an asp.net application which communicates with web services. However quite often of late, the services have been down. I don't want to throw a generic Exception but rather a very specific one. What is the Exception name that handles 'connection timed out'. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct one to throw is [TimeoutException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timeoutexception.aspx). The default message is `The operation has timed-out`

From MSDN:

> The exception that is thrown when the time allotted for a process or operation has expired.

Comment: I have to wait 9 minutes before I access your answer. Will do tho. Thanks!

Comment: @Dragan Glad it helped :) No rush